# replacing consecutive identical character using replace and replaceAll in Java

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I'd like to replace all occurrences of 2 consecutive commas (",,") by a marker in between, but I've found that I can't replace the second occurrence. The code is as follows:

```
String addresses = "a,,,b";
String b = addresses.replace(",,", ",EMPTYADDR,");
System.out.println(b);
```

I expect the result to be:

```
a,EMPTYADDR,EMPTYADDR,b
```

But instead, I get:

```
a,EMPTYADDR,,b
```

How should I change the code to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3):

Pass lookaround based regex in `replaceAll` function. Lookarounds won't consume any character but asserts whether a match is possible or not.

```
string.replaceAll("(?<=,)(?=,)", "EMPTYADDR");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nR2iR3/1)

- `(?<=,)` tells the regex engine to lookafter to all the commas.
- `(?=,)` tells the regex engine to match all the boundaries which exists after all the commas only if it's followed by another comma.
- So two boundaries are being matched. By replacing the matched boundaries with `EMPTYADDR` will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Simple non-Regex method using a `while` loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String addresses = "a,,,b";
    while (addresses.contains(",,")){
        addresses = addresses.replace(",,", ",EMPTYADDR,");
    }
    System.out.println(addresses);
}
```

Results:

```
a,EMPTYADDR,EMPTYADDR,b
```

You could also split the string, fill in the empty elements, and then reconstruct with `String.join()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String addresses = "a,,,b";
    String[] pieces = addresses.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
        if (pieces[i].isEmpty()) {
            pieces[i] = "EMPTYADDR";
        }
    }

    addresses = String.join(",", pieces);
    System.out.println(addresses);
}
```